# Can MainActivity behave the way a WearableListenerService does in Android/Wear OS

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

My WearDataLayerListenerService which extends WearableListenerService gets onDataChanged events when the wearable app is closed. I either need to pass a photo asset from the WearDataLayerListenerService to the MainActivity or find a way to make the MainActivity behave the way the WearDataLayerListenerService. Does anybody know if this is possible? I thought passing around a photo asset would not be very efficient.

My manifest looks like this:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
    android:value="false"/>
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<service
    android:name=".WearDataLayerListenerService"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.DATA_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.MESSAGE_RECEIVED" />
        <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/start-activity" />
        <data android:scheme="wear" android:host="*" android:pathPrefix="/message/mobile" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: If you're worried about "efficiency", don't call `getAsset()`until after you start your `Activity` from the listener `Service`.

Comment: How do I get the main activity to use the DataEventBuffer dataEventBuffer without the onDataChanged being called? The big challenge is that it does not fire in the MainActivity if it is not open or is opened after the .WearDataLayerListenerService opens it.